# Hibernate Criteria - How to apply functions to ORDER BY?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

It sounded like a simple problem, but I found no easy solution online.

---

I am trying to replicate the current `ORDER BY` in Hibernate, without succes:

```
SELECT * FROM IPEM.DEMANDE
WHERE INIT_DATE >= TO_TIMESTAMP('23/04/2021', 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND INIT_DATE <= 
TO_TIMESTAMP('29/04/2021', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
ORDER BY TO_TIMESTAMP(LIMIT_DATE, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), TO_TIMESTAMP(INIT_DATE , 'dd/MM/yyyy') ASC <<< this line
```

Why ? Because I have this kind of data in my database:

```
05/05/2021 00:00:00 - 23/04/2021 00:00:00
05/05/2021 00:00:00 - 28/04/2021 00:00:00 << this should be 3rd
05/05/2021 02:00:00 - 24/04/2021 00:00:00 << this should be 2nd
```

The hours mess up the sorting. I'm trying to ignore them/format the date before loading my entries. A way I found to do so is applying `TO_TIMESTAMP` to `ORDER_BY`. It works well in SQL, but when going to Hibernate, it is not that simple.

Actually, my code looks like this:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(fieldName));
```

I tried some trivial solution, which obviously did not work:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("TO_TIMESTAMP(" + fieldName + ", 'dd/MM/yyyy')");
```

For which I had the following error (`limitDate` is the Java name, `LIMIT_DATE` the corresponding column):

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: TO_TIMESTAMP(limitDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

---

How can I apply `TO_TIMESTAMP` to the members of my `ORDER BY` ? (No worries, we assume here all the members are dates, both in Java and in the SQL Table).

Comment: if LIMIT_DATE is a date you don't need to invoke TO_TIMESTAMP before ordering by LIMIT_DATE. does LIMIT_DATE's column contain sql dates?

Comment: I need to either invoke TO_TIMESTAMP or restrict the sorting to day/month/year only, the hours mess up with my sorting. Yes, they contain SQL Dates (iirc). I will add my use case so that it is clearer.

Comment: could you create a native query? at database level should LIMIT_DATE and INIT_DATE be timestamp? could you change the sql type of the column?

Comment: I could create a native query, however that would ask for a lot of work: the pre-existing codebase uses the Hibernate API. I can't change the SQL type of the column, unfortunately either. I think I cannot do this the way I wanted with Hibernate and that's that.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, but you can subclass `Order` and override the `org.hibernate.criterion.Order#toSqlString` method to implement whatever logic you need. Anyway, you should move away from the legacy Criteria API to the JPA Criteria API. There you could use `criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.function("TO_TIMESTAMP", root.get(fieldName), criteriaBuilder.literal("dd/MM/yyyy")))`

Comment: That's what I feared, I would have to re-write the whole code block in order for it to work ... Thank you for your answer !